# Is it possible to use maven versions:set of a dependency that uses a placeholder?

Tags: maven

Given a dependency which uses the placeholder project.version, is it possible to set the version to another version?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>a-b</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried some variants of this:

```
mvn versions:set -DgroupId=a.b.c -DartifactId=a-b -DoldVersion=${project.version} -DnewVersion=1.0
```

This works when the oldVersion gets concrete values like 4.54 but not with the placeholder ${project.version}. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Why do you like to replace `${project.version}` ?

Comment: At some point i want to switch from snapshots to concrete versions.

Comment: Where is the property defined? You can use the property project.version and still facilitate the version plugin to update the property.

Comment: ${project.version} targets the <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> tag of the given pom.

Comment: The whole point of using the project.version property is so don't have to do what you are attempting to do. Maven will replace it at execution time with whatever the version of the project is. If you release your project it will resolve to `1.0.0` for the release build.

Comment: That is true, in this case project and dependency are the same version when we are at the snapshot stage, but i need to set different versions for project and dependency at later stages. Is there a way?